# c[l][k] is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to remove this Firebug Console Error from last few hours. The error which I am getting is:

```
c[l][k] is not a constructor
jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js (line 10)
```

Any siggestions would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: works for me :P any additional info?

Comment: Very difficult to figure out what's wrong when the error is coming from the minified version of jquery-ui.  Could you include the non-minified version instead and see what error you get?

Comment: @BishopRook, not that hard. Just Ctrl+F `c[l][k]` and figure out what variables they match up to :)

Comment: are you sure persist tab is not clicked??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be , duplication of the jQuery file

Comment: Got it. When I removed the file "jquery-tabs.js", i didnt get the error again. But, I will need this file for showing tabs in my page. Is ther eany other suggestion for this too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters how about upgrading jquery-ui? 1.7.1 an ancient! At least go to 1.7.3 and better is 1.8.15.

Can you paste the code that triggers it?

If you don't know how to do that (or it's just too big), you start cutting your app in half. Remove half, then see if it works, if it does you know the bug was in the other half. Then you start cutting the halfs in half till you narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Got it. When I removed the file "jquery-tabs.js", i didnt get the error again. But, I will need this file for showing tabs in my page. Is there any other suggestion for this too.

Comment: The first thing I would do is upgrade all your jquery stuff. Make sure all the jquery-ui versions match, and have the jquery version itself be the version that was released at the same time (check the date when your chosen version of jquery-ui was released).

Comment: I changed my jQuery UI to "jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js". The previous error got removed. But now I am getting this error:  c.ui.dialog is undefined at jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js(line 377).

Comment: Do you like old versions or something? 1.8.10 is also old. The current version is 1.8.15. And make sure to upgrade ALL the jquery libraries you use (tabs, etc.).

Comment: I upgraded my JQuery to 1.8.15. Now its working all fine... Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is coming from here in the non minified version:

```
$.data(this, name, new $[namespace][name](this, options))._init());
```

- `$` = `c`
- `namespace` = `l`
- `name` = `k`

This line means there is an error with one of your widgets. Perhaps it was designed for a different version of jQuery that you are using. I recommend upgrading both your jQuery UI and your jQuery.

Which widgets are you making use of?